# Cannot get login to redirect to home page if the user is registered on database

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I cannot seem to link my login page to my home page, any help would be much appreciated. I know its connecting to the database as i can create users but for some reason its not letting me sign in with a created user.

```
<?php require ("insert.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST[ 'Login' ]))
    {
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['email']);
    $pswrd= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['pswrd']);

    $result = $con->query (" select * from users where email='$email' AND pswrd='$pswrd' ");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["User ID"] = $row['UserID'];
    header ('Location: home.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>AMSadler login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="Anthony">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="index" href="index.php">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="AMSadler.com"/></a>
            </div>

            <div id="signup">
                <button type="button"><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <input id="Login" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div id="copyright">
                <p>&copy Copyright 2015</p>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: forms default to what when a method is omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your form tags.

From,

```
<form>
```

To,

```
<form action="yourPageName.php" method="post">
```

You need to specify your `method` type so in your `PHP` code you can get it using that method. If you leave out the `method` part it by default uses `$_GET`. Seeing as your code is pointing to `$_POST` then you set it to `method="post"`.

You also need to set `action=""` this can be set to `#` for same page or leave it blank or using a file name. This will redirect the form to that page.

Comment: Oh boy i cannot believe i missed that thank you so much, I am new at this

Comment: @AnthonySadler no problem. Glad I could help. Click the green tick if my answer helped you.

Comment: blank for same page not #

Comment: @Script47 check if query return result because now all people can be log :)

Comment: Hmm it is working however now when i am redirected to my home page and i  place in this code 
<?php 
require ("insert.php"); 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
}
else {
 echo "session not transferring";
}
?> with an echo statement of <?php echo $_SESSION["UserID"];?> in my page it is not working any suggestions?

Comment: Call `session_start` first not `require`.